# R subsetting a Data Frame excluding certain values from Column

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

i have a data frame that has certain values ending in `(SP1)` or `(SP2)`along with other values that do not end with `(SP1)` or `(SP2)`.
what i am trying to accomplish is to create a new data frame that contains only the values that do not end on `(SP1)` or `(SP2)`

i can subset the values containing `(SP1)` or `(SP2)` as below:

`Loc.Z.End = subset(location.simple, grepl("(SP1)|(SP2)", location.simple$Location_Name))`

i thought that adding the `!` operator would do the trick as below but it does not!

`Loc.Z.End = subset(location.simple, [!grepl("(SP1)|(SP2)", location.simple$Location_Name)])`

but this does not do the trick! what am i doing wrong?

here is an exaple of the data

`Location_Name               City
     AMEM01                 London
     BANY01                 Leeds
     HSBC Dubai (SP1)       Dubai
     Leeds(SP2)             Leeds`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument that takes the `grepl` logical expression is `subset` and according to `?subset`

> subset - logical expression indicating elements or rows to keep:
>   missing values are taken as false.

We don't need any `[]`

```
subset(location.simple, !grepl("(SP1)|(SP2)", location.simple$Location_Name))
#  Location_Name   City
#1        AMEM01 London
#2        BANY01  Leeds
```

Comment: as usual, thanks for your guidance! i thought i needed the `[]` for some reason and did not even think about not using them!